# Как перенаправить запрос из Servlet в JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы  Servlet перенаправил запрос в JSP. Использую RequestDispatcher.

Вот код сервлета:

```
public class ServletDispatcher extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);

    }
}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.geraltsx.library.web.controlers.ServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp лежит в папке web проекта, по соседству с WEB-INF:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Документ</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>пРивет</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Использую сервер GlassFish. При заходе в браузере на url http://localhost:8080/app/servlet выдает 404 ошибку((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в не верном деплое проекта. Код сам рабочий

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp")` или `request.getRequestDispatcher("/app/index.jsp")`.